# Parametrized SQL on Postgres with ARRAY

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, prepared-statement, plpgsql

I am running the below SQL and it works fine:

```
  const ids = book.map(({ id }) => id);
  const myQuery = `
    SELECT
      row_to_json(s)
    FROM (
      SELECT
        b.id, b.event_id, b.title, b.price, e.account_id
      FROM
        ticket_books b, event e
      WHERE
        b.event_id = e.id AND
        b.id = ANY(ARRAY[${ids}])
    ) s
  `;
  const result = await server.pg.query(myQuery);
```

I would like to switch to prepared statements, so I rewrote the above as:

```
  const myQuery = `
    SELECT
      row_to_json(s)
    FROM (
      SELECT
        b.id, b.event_id, b.title, b.price, e.account_id
      FROM
        ticket_books b, event e
      WHERE
        b.event_id = e.id AND
        b.id = ANY(ARRAY[$1])
    ) s
  `;
  const result = await server.pg.query(myQuery, [ids]);
```

The prepared statement version is failing with: `error: operator does not exist: integer = text`.

What is the problem?

Comment: What is in `ids`? Is it an array of integers or strings?

Comment: a bunch of integers. it is constructed at the beginning of the code.

Comment: Are you sure they're integers and not strings?

Comment: If you hard code `const ids = [1,2,3]` does it work?

Comment: i am pretty sure ids are of type `number`.

Comment: Are you pretty sure, or are you sure? Verify it or hard code an array of numbers. An array of strings would cause the problem you're having.

Comment: My mistake. pg is doing something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pg will make the array for you. Use `b.id = ANY($1)`.